# C# form numeric up down

Tags: c#, forms, numericupdown

I want to use TextChanged in C# form to bind numeric up down but when I try it the calculated sum from this field is lower by 1 than it should be (the value is late by 1).

```
private void tbSoucet3_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Soucet();
    SoucetKratTrackbar();
}
```

Comment: What are the `Soucet` and `SoucetKratTrackbar` methods? Also, why are you using `TextChanged` event, instead of `ValueChanged`?

Comment: Soucet() is for sum, SoucetKratTrackbar() is for sum * value of the trackbar. Value change has the same bad result. And also when I manually add value to numeric up down, I must click to other field to get result and that result is correct, but clicking to the arrow gives me value late by 1.

Comment: at: sum * value. could the reason for "value late by 1" be that either sum or value is at 0?

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] I must use text changed. It didn't work because I forgot to change left side of command to TextChanged from ValueChanged in designer.